# Python for kivy:Pass values between multiple screens

Tags: python, kivy

I am developing a kivy app in which ,there are two screens 
**1.LoginScreen**
 and **2.HomeScreen.**

**What  required  is -**
 A value 'xyz' which is computed in class `LoginScreen`, to be passed to the method `'insertdata'` of class `HomeScreen` and want to display that value on a label.

For this I tried following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager


class loginScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(HomeScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def auth(self):
        xyz=1
        self.manager.current="home"
        obj=HomeScreen()
        # 1. To Pass 'xyz' to method scrn2 
        HomeScreen.insertdata(obj)


class HomeScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        if (a==1):
            # 2. To display label
        self.scrn2()

    def insertdata(self):
        print "screen 2"
        label=Label(text="good moring")
        self.add_widget(label)


class ScreenApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScreenApp().run()
```

Here:

- **insertdata is called from method auth**

1)the 1st way is proper , as it is passing 'xyz' and calling the method    `insertdata` but it **dosen't display label**

2) in 1st way I have to create to create an object of HomeScreen ,to call `insertdata`, which in turn calls the `___init__` of `Homescreen` and **`init`**  calls `insertdata`

- **insertdata called from __init__**

1) It loads data before user authentication at loginscreen

`insertdata` gets total *3 calls*, which is affecting app launch time.

Suggest me any simple and effective way for this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Screen.manager()` method to get an manager object from one screen, use it to retrieve another one with its `ScreenManager.get_screen()` method and then pass the value directly. For an working example check an answer of this question: [Kivy - Slider Class value change on another screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29419109/kivy-slider-class-value-change-on-another-screen/29420233)