# How to make data sharing between kivy python screens?

Tags: python, kivy

such a problem I am writing a very simplified IMDb application on kivy. I ran into a problem that I can’t exchange data between screens (For example, I want to make it so that after pressing a button on the first screen, the label accepts and displays it, or so that a certain number of buttons are created on the second screen, based on which button was pressed on the first screen). Help me please!

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import *

class MovieInfo(Screen):
    def __init__(self, name="MovieInfo"):
        super(MovieInfo, self).__init__(name=name)
        alNavigationBar = AnchorLayout(anchor_x="center", anchor_y="top", padding=(25, 20, 25, 15))
        glNavigationBar = GridLayout(cols=2, rows=1, size_hint_y=None)

        backBtn = Button(text="<-", size_hint=(None, None), size=(100, 100), on_press=self.pressBackButton)
        glNavigationBar.add_widget(backBtn)
        alNavigationBar.add_widget(glNavigationBar)

        informs = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', spacing=15, size_hint_y=None, padding=(25, 25, 25, 10))
        informs.bind(minimum_height=informs.setter('height'))
        for i in range(50):
            label = Label(text=f"{i}", size_hint_y=None, font_size='18sp')
            informs.add_widget(label)
        scrollInforms = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height - 100))
        scrollInforms.add_widget(informs)

        self.add_widget(alNavigationBar)
        self.add_widget(scrollInforms)

    def pressBackButton(self, instance):
        self.manager.current = "MovieList"



class Movies(Screen):
    def __init__(self, name="MovieList"):
        super(Movies, self).__init__(name=name)
        alNavigationBar = AnchorLayout(anchor_x="center", anchor_y="top", padding=(25, 20, 25, 15))
        glNavigationBar = GridLayout(cols=2, rows=1, size_hint_y=None)

        backBtn = Button(text="<-", size_hint=(None, None), size=(100, 100), on_press=self.pressBackButton)
        glNavigationBar.add_widget(backBtn)
        alNavigationBar.add_widget(glNavigationBar)

        moviesList = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', spacing=15, size_hint_y=None, padding=(25, 25, 25, 10))
        moviesList.bind(minimum_height=moviesList.setter('height'))
        for i in range(50):
            movieButton = Button(text=f"{i}", size_hint_y=None, height=140, on_press=self.pressMovieButton)
            moviesList.add_widget(movieButton)
        scrollMoviesList = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height - 120))
        scrollMoviesList.add_widget(moviesList)

        self.add_widget(alNavigationBar)
        self.add_widget(scrollMoviesList)

    def pressBackButton(self, instance):
        self.manager.current = "GenresList"

    def pressMovieButton(self, instance):
        print(instance.text)
        self.manager.current = "MovieInfo"


class Genres(Screen):
    def __init__(self, name="GenresList"):
        super(Genres, self).__init__(name=name)
        alInputText = AnchorLayout(anchor_x="center", anchor_y="top", padding=(10, 20, 10, 0))

        inputText = TextInput(hint_text='Enter movie name', multiline=False, font_size=40, size_hint=(0.97, 0.05),
                          on_text_validate=self.inputMoviesName)
        alInputText.add_widget(inputText)

        genresList = GridLayout(cols=2, spacing=15, size_hint_y=None, padding=(25, 0, 25, 10))
        genresList.bind(minimum_height=genresList.setter('height'))
        for i in range(50):
            genreButton = Button(text=f"{i}", size_hint_y=None, height=350, on_press=self.pressGenreButton)
            genresList.add_widget(genreButton)
        scrollGenresList = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height - 100))
        scrollGenresList.add_widget(genresList)

        self.add_widget(alInputText)
        self.add_widget(scrollGenresList)

    def inputMoviesName(self, instance):
        print(instance.text)
        instance.text = " "
        self.manager.current = "MovieList"

    def pressGenreButton(self, instance):
        print(instance.text)
        self.manager.current = "MovieList"


class Application(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = "MyIMDb"
        scrManager = ScreenManager(transition=NoTransition())
        screens = [
            Genres(),
            Movies(),
            MovieInfo()
        ]
        for i in screens:
            scrManager.add_widget(i)
        return scrManager


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Application().run()
```

I don’t have much experience and I am just a beginner programmer, so I don’t know much

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of the question but I think the answer might be somewhere in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29419109/kivy-slider-class-value-change-on-another-screen/29420233).
It explains how to use the screen manager to change some value in another screen, then you can probably use the *on_enter* method to be sure everything is aligned.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587

Comment: You're definitely right, let's say I didn't understand the question enough to mark it as a duplicate, which probably is, or write a full out-of-track answer, but I didn't want to leave it as a dead end. Is this considered bad? Do SO internal links rot too?

Comment: the link rot argument applies less, but maybe still does. questions and answers _can_ be deleted (see the Help Center for more info on that). In any case, my understanding is that any answer should be understandable on its own if you strip out the link's href.